# Port Forwarding Bypass

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

A while ago I thought of a potential solution to bypassing the port forwarding requirement. I doubt it would work, but it would be nice if someone could explain why.

So you have two computers, A and B, and they each only have 1 public facing IP. Neither is port forwarded, but A is the server. B connects to some cloud service to get A’s IP and notify A of B’s IP. They then each send a message to every port on the other’s public facing IP until one of them gets through. The idea is if one of them has already sent a message from their port to the other’s port, and the other one sends one too, the router will think it is a response and allow it through.

This would obviously only work in an idealistic world at best, but would it work at all?

Comment: "This would obviously only work in an idealistic world at best, but would it work at all?" - What you describe is a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Tailscale's blog post](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works/) on this topic, which also compares several different kinds of NAT implementations.

When at least one machine is behind a "compatible" NAT:

> If we stick with a fairly modest probing rate of 100 ports/sec, half the time we’ll get through in under 2 seconds. And even if we get unlucky, 20 seconds in we’re virtually guaranteed to have found a way in, after probing less than 4% of the total search space.

When both machines are behind "symmetric NAT" which randomizes the ports:

> We can try to apply the same trick, but now the search is much harder: each random destination port we probe through a hard NAT also results in a random source port. That means we’re now looking for a collision on a {source port, destination port} pair, rather than just the destination port.
>
> Again I’ll spare you the calculations, but after 20 seconds in the same regime as the previous setup (256 probes from one side, 2048 from the other), our chance of success is… 0.01%.